# Animação suave da div de baixo após remoção da div de cima

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3, front-end

Segue código abaixo. Basicamente eu queria que a `div.div2` tivesse uma 'subida' mais suave:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            body{
                margin: 0; padding: 0;
            }
            div{
                width: 90%;
                height: 50px;
                background-color: red;
                margin: 20px auto;
            }
            .div1{
                animation: anim 2s forwards;
                animation-delay: 2s;
            }
            .div2{
    
            }
    
            @keyframes anim{
                0%{
                    transform: translateX(0%);
                }
                100%{
                    transform: translateX(-200%);
                    display: none;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="div1">
        </div>
        
        <div class="div2">
        </div>
    </body>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout( function () {
                $('.div1').remove();
            }, 3000);
        });
    </script>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Esse tipo de transição geralmente é feita transicionando o `height` do elemento até `0px` e depois removendo o elemento.

Comment: Fernando entendo, mas a div de cima não pode ser transicionada dessa forma porque ela tem dados que devem ser exibidos...

Comment: Se o `height` não for transicionado a remoção do elemento vai não vai ser suave. Mas preste atenção que eu não disse que o elemento precisa estar visível. Você pode, por exemplo, transicionar o `opacity` de `1` até `0`, e só após isso transicionar o `height`. Dessa maneira o conteúdo não vai ser "achatado" na animação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode utilizar o `.animate()` do jQuery. Após decorrer o `.setTimeout()`, pegue a diferença negativa da posição da segunda div da primeira em relação ao topo, aí você anima a segunda div antes de remover a primeira usando o valor negativo.

Por exemplo: a div1 está a `20px` do topo, e a div2 `90px`, logo a diferença é de `70px`. Então você vai aplicar `-70px` na animação com a propriedade `top`. Quando a div1 for removida, você volta a div pra posição `top: 0`, porque a `div1` já não irá ocupar espaço na página.

Para isso é preciso colocar também no CSS a propriedade `position: relative` na div2 para poder movimentá-la:

Veja funcionando:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout( function () {
      var d1 = $('.div1').offset().top;
      var d2 = $('.div2').offset().top;

      $('.div2').animate({
         top: -(d2-d1)} , 500, function(){
            $('.div1').remove();
            $(this).css("top", "0");
      });
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
body{
   margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
div{
   width: 90%;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: red;
   margin: 20px auto;
}
.div1{
   animation: anim 2s forwards;
   animation-delay: 2s;
}
.div2{
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes anim{
   0%{
       transform: translateX(0%);
   }
   100%{
       transform: translateX(-200%);
       display: none;
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Você controla a velocidade da animação aumentando ou diminuindo o valor `500`. Se aumentar, a animação dura mais tempo; se diminuir, mais rápido. Esse valor é em milissegundos, ou seja, `500` significa meio segundo.

### Forma genérica com ação ao clique de um botão: **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h5ja8dL6/1/)**

Comment: Entendi! Sam, como eu generalizo para n divs. Nas quais qualquer uma delas pode ser removida?

Comment: Mas vc está fazendo animação no CSS. Logo vc sabe que div está sendo removida

Comment: Mas esse exemplo é diferente do meu código real, no real ele é uma lista de produtos em um carrinho, dai o cliente pode remover qualquer uma das "divs"

Comment: Ah sim. Então a divulgação é removida ao clique de um botão

Comment: É, basicamente isso.

Comment: Então é mais complexo. Vou ter que refazer o código. Mais tarde eu faço pq agora tô na rua.

Comment: Amanhã eu faço pra vc... É q minha máquina tá em manutenção

Comment: Obrigado Sam, aguardo a sua resposta amigo.

Comment: Adicionei no final da resposta um link para o JSFiddle.